# generating buttons to update inventory in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Okay so I'm a bit lost here as I'm very new to AJAX and fairly new to PHP. So I have an inventory management system build with phpmyadmin and wamp. The registration/ log in system works great. so when the user logs in a table of all inventory is generated on screen, along with a button next to each inventory item that allows the current user to check in or check out an item. the buttons are all generated and I gave them a unique id using php and the code looks like this.

```
    <table class = "table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><center><strong>Item Id</strong></center> </td>
            <td><center><strong>Item Description</strong></center> </td>
            <td><center><strong>Item Type</strong> </center></td>
            <td><center><strong>Availability</strong></center></td>
            <td><center><strong>Name</strong></center></td>
            <td><center><strong>Check in/out button</strong></center></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        mysql_select_db('inventory management system');
        $query="SELECT * FROM inventory";
        $results = mysql_query($query);
        $a = 0;

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
          $a++;
          echo '<script type = "text/javascript">c++;</script>'
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><center><?php echo $row['item_id']?></center></td>
                <td><center><?php echo $row['item_desc']?></center></td>
                <td><center><?php echo $row['item_type']?></center></td>
                <td><center><?php echo $row['availability_status']?></center></td>
                <td><center><?php echo $row['name']?></center></td>
                <td><center><?php
                if(is_null($row['name'])){
//this is what is generating each button with a unique id                  echo '<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Check Out"  id = "<?php echo $a; ?>" onclick="<?php  ?>">';
                }else if(!is_null($row['name'])){
                  echo '<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Check In"  id = "<?php echo $a; ?>" onclick="updateinventory()">';

                }


                 ?></center></td>
            </tr>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

so now when the user clicks a button, it updates the database to set the name field to null signifying that nobody has the item checked out, that way another user can sign in and check out an item in the inventory. I'm really struggling and have tried everything from on click methods (which for some reason I couldn't get to work) to plenty of things with ajax and php.. and I cant get a seemingly simple feature to work... Thank you for any possible help.

Comment: You're telling us that you're quite new to PHP. I'd **strongly** advise you not to use `mysql_*` functions. They've been deprecated for more than 2 years now. I wouldn't be suprised if your application is wide open to SQL injection. That means that your users can break (intentionally or not) everything very easily. Not to mention completely erasing your database. MySQLi or PDO with Prepared Statements are the way to go these days.

Comment: @icecub yea theres a lot more to my code than youre seeing. I have taken all measures to prevent sql injections for multiple things. I used trim, strip tags, and the htmlspecialchars methods in php to handle any possible sql injecting. Truthfully its just what I was taught php and sql a few years back. But I never got crazy into it until recently so I'm getting used to all the new stuff :3

Comment: Those will not protect you completely. Hence the reason they've removed `mysql_*` functions from php7 and up. So even if you feel comfortable enough with what you have, as soon as you have no choice but to update your server, you're going to have to rewrite your entire code as it simply no longer works. Might as well do it right from the start :)

Comment: And if you feel a bit uncomfortable about it because it seems quite complicated, feel free to send me an email (you can find it on my profile). I'm always willing to help out new programmers that truely wish to learn something. You'll see it's not that difficult at all. You'll get the hang of it within an hour :)

Comment: @icecub that would be so amazing if you can do that. ive been looking for someone to actually be able to go to for help rather than teach myself everything and not get different perspectives. My issue would be a lot easier to explain if I can show you all the code. but its too much to paste here and itll be to hard to understand without actually seeing it all..

Comment: Actually showing me everything would mean we have to use Teamviewer. Even though I know I can be trusted, it's not a smart thing to allow a stranger to take over your computer. It's your choice though

Answer (score 0):

You have already opened php tags so change

```
echo '<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Check In"  id = 
"<?php echo $a; ?>" onclick="updateinventory()">';
```

to

```
 echo "<input class='btn btn-default' type='submit' value='Check In'  
 id ='$a' onclick='updateinventory()'>";
```

Similarly remove php tags from `IF` since php starting tags have been written above.

`type="submit"` this will directly submit the page, and you probably need to make it `button` so that you may call javascript function that will eventually call ajax.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Wouldn't the single quotes around the variable cause an issue? I know the main string is in double quotes so this got me in a bit of a doubt about it

Comment: That's a great start. My syntax is completely off, I'm so not used to programming in these languages so thanks a ton for that tip.

Comment: @icecub I would work in this scenario, you can do it like this as well `'".$a." '` and that should work fine, here is an example `$name="danyal";
echo "<input type='name' value='$name' />";
`

Comment: Thanks. I was simply curious about it :)